# Click function no longer working after an update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following fiddle if you click on a button/tab on the left, you can see an arrow type figure appears on the right of the tab.

https://jsfiddle.net/5mf989jL/49/

With every tab you select the arrow is placed on that tab.

This was prior to my updated code. Now my arrow only appears when the first tab is clicked on and it is a lot higher than it should be.

I changed this...

```
$('.panel_out input').on('click', function () {
    var id_to_show = '#' + this.id.replace('_button', '');
    $(id_to_show).show().siblings().hide();
}).first().trigger('click');
```

To this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.panel_out input').on('click', function () {
        var id_to_show = '#' + this.id.replace('_button', '');
        $(id_to_show).show().siblings().hide();
        $('#dashboard_welcome').siblings().hide();
```

The arrow function comes from this...

```
//For the arrow in panel
$("input.arrowBtn").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.arrow-left').remove();
    $("<div class='arrow-left'></div>").insertAfter($(this));
});
```

How can I alter this so that it does the same as it does in the fiddle?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your updated code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/5mf989jL/50/

Comment: The arrow shows on each tab click, whether it's the first or another tab.
what do you mean by: "it is a lot higher than it should be"?

Comment: can you please resend me the jsfiddle with your updated code only
which is making problem, because you only pasted some part of your updated script

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5mf989jL/55/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line at the end instead of in the first function.

```
$('.panel_out input').first().trigger('click');
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/5mf989jL/50/)**

Comment: I don't want that line in there anymore. That is why I removed it. I need this to work with what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .panel_out css
set width to 20%, it will make your menu align with its right side panel

```
.panel_out {
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: #707070;
    background-color: #707070;
}
```

where is the script problem you are talking about??? look in screenshot its working

[image]

Comment: what?? I'm confused with this answer.

Comment: sorry it was not 21 it was 20

Comment: if you want your both panels align you said your menu is lot higher 
"This was prior to my updated code. Now my arrow only appears when the first tab is clicked on and it is a lot higher than it should be."

Comment: The css for the panel is not the issue. It is the javascript that is causing the issue.

Comment: The arrow only shows on one button. That is the issue.

Comment: ok ill update my answer but first give me your code which is making problem because the jsfiddle link you provided here is working fine, arrow is moving to clicked tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88120/discussion-between-muhammad-irfan-and-paul).

Comment: I did provide that code. It is in my question. The middle code block. That change started the issue.